# Proportion of edges within a fraction of the diameter

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, isogenies

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a finite, connected $k$-regular graph of diameter $D$. Fixing some $\epsilon>0$ and letting $v$ be a (random) element of $V$, what proportion of the other edges are at most $\epsilon\cdot D$ steps away from $v$?

To be more exact, I'm looking at Ramanujan graphs that are $l+1$ regular for some prime $l$, and hence I know that if $n = |V|$, the diameter will be very close to $\log_l(n)$. For my purposes, $n = M^2\cdot p$ for some other primes $M$ and $p$ (which will be very large), so the diameter will be $2\log_l(M)+\log_l(p)$. I start at some edge $v_0$ and can only make at most $\log_l(M)$ steps, so if $M$ is about $p$, this is 1/3 of the total diameter.

I'm curious if I can say something about the chance that a random vertex $v\in V$ will be reachable under this setup, i.e. the chance that $d(v,v_0)\leq \log_l(M)$.

Any help is much  appreciated!